# interfaceを具象の構造体に型変換できない

Tags: go

以下のように`Model`インターフェイスと`Tag`構造体があります。`Tag`構造体は`Model`インターフェイスを実装しています。

[Modelインターフェイス]

```
type Model interface {
  Serialize() []string   
}
```

[Tag構造体]

```
type Tag struct {
  Id   int    `db:"id"`
  Name string `db:"Name"`
}
func (tag Tag) Serialize() []string {
  ...
}
```

そして、以下のような`GetModel`関数があり、`model_type`に`tag`を渡すと、`Tag`型のデータが返却されます。この時、`GetModel`の戻り値の型は`Model`インターフェイスを指定していますが、`Tag`構造体は`Model`インターフェイスを実装しているためちゃんと動きます。

```
// func GetModel(model_type string) Tag {
func GetModel(model_type string) Model {
  if model_type == "tag" {
    return Tag{}
  } else if model_type == "xxx" {
    return Xxx{}
  } else {
    return Yyy{}
  }
    return nil
  }
}
```

しかしながら、以下に示すような、`Tag`構造体の`Id`メンバへのアクセスができません。

```
model := GetModel(model_type)
fmt.Println(model.Id)
```

変数`model`の型は`reflect.TypeOf()`で確認しましたが、`Tag`であることは確認できましたが、`model.Id`にアクセスすると、`Model`インターフェイスにはIdというメンバも関数もないという旨のエラーメッセージが出てきます。`model.(Tag)`のようにキャストさせてみたのですが、これも同じ結果でした。

どのようにすれば想定通りに動かすことができるのか、ぜひアドバイスをいただきたく思います。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: go version 1.10.1 で実行してみましたが、type assertion すれば(`model := GetModel(model_type).(Tag)`) 、`model.Id` にアクセスすることができました。

Comment: @metropolis さん、 ほんとだ！動きました！！めっちゃ助かりました！！！

Comment: 一応、GetModel() 関数は Tag 型以外の型も返す様なので [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) を使うことをお勧めします。

Comment: @metropolis  いろいろ調べてみましたら、型アサーションか型スイッチで処理するみたいですね。ただ、抽象化レイヤがある数だけ型スイッチをしなければいけない、というのは自分では腑に落ちない部分もあります。こんなに面倒なのかなgo言語って??と少し感じてしまいました。ただ、調べてみても答えは型スイッチだと思うので、型スイッチで実装をして行こうと思います！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント欄にもある通り、以下で対応できました。

```
model := GetModel(model_type).(Tag)
```

また、interfaceのような抽象的な型を構造体のような具象的な型として利用するときは、逐一、型アサーションや型スイッチ構文を利用する必要があるみたいです。